# One die has one side marked 1, two sides marked 2, three sides marked 3

Tags: probability, combinations

Question is: what is the average number of throws we needed to have all the numbers `1`, `2`, `3` appeared at least once each.

Comment: If anyone need answer, I can provide. However I need the detailed reasoning and derive.

Comment: related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1802415/why-was-i-wrong-about-the-monster-gem-riddler

Comment: The accepted answer in the monster gem link actually calculates the answer to this question as 7.3. Is this then a duplicate?

Comment: One die, two dice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For each subset $S\subset\{1,2,3\}$ denote by $E_S$ the expected number of additional throws when we already have seen the members of $S$. Then $E_{123}=0$, and we want to know $E_\emptyset$.

We then obtain seven equations of the following type:
$$\eqalign{
E_{\emptyset}&=1+{1\over6}E_1+{1\over3}E_2+{1\over2}E_3\cr E_1&=1+{1\over6}E_1+{1\over3}E_{12}+{1\over2}E_{13}\ ,\cr}$$
etcetera. Solving this system leads to $E_{\emptyset}={73\over10}$.